# Using multiline regexps in Perl 5

Tags: regex, perl

I read the manuals about using multiline regexes in Perl 5, but still cannot figure out why the following ones don't work as intended:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.20;

my $s = <<'ENDSTR';
aaa       : AAA
bbb       : BBB
ccc       : CCC
ENDSTR

my $m = 'bbb';

my $a = $s =~ s/.*^$m *: (.*?)$.*/$1/rsm;
my $b = $s =~ s/[.\n]*?^$m *: (.*)$[.\n]*/$1/rm;

print "a: $a\n";
print "b: $b\n";
```

The intended output of the program is

```
a: BBB
b: BBB
```

But these regexes produce:

```
a: BBB
ccc       : CCC

b: aaa       : AAA
bbb       : BBB
ccc       : CCC
```

How to correct these regexes in order to get the needed matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On perlmonks.org I was advised with the correct variant:

```
my $a = $1 if  $s =~ s/^$m *: (.*?)$/$1/rsm;
my $b = $1 if  $s =~ s/^$m *: (.*)$/$1/rm;
```

Answer (score 0):

With the s flag you are allowing the . meta character to match line endings. Either remove it or change the .* at the end of the regex to .*?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be easier to split that string by both `\s*:\s*` and `\n`. You can build a hash very easily with the output, although this approach won't work if you have `:` in one of your strings, while your regular expression does. The following code works for me:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.20;

my $s = <<'ENDSTR';
aaa       : AAA
bbb       : BBB
ccc       : CCC
ENDSTR

my %hash = split(/(\s*:?\s*|\n)/, $s);
say $hash{'bbb'};
```

If you're trying to parse data in that format, you should try using `Config::General`, which [can parse a simple configuration file format](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Config-General/General.pm#CONFIG_FILE_FORMAT) that's pretty similar to what you have, but also supports comments, blocks, and other cool things.

Comment: You are right, for parsing such a simple string regexes aren't needed at all. But this string was used just for simple example of how multiline regexes work.